# How to add Required Field conditionally camparing an json element width child element of it's sibling json element in Json Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a sample JSON file with a JSON-Schema. In this, I want to specify the **password** as ***required*** if the **category** is "**Private**" and **type** in **confidential** is "**Customer**". Otherwise, password is not required. How to compare the values in the definition at if-else-then which is not inside of that definition.

> schema.json

```
  {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["name", "email"],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "pattern": "(^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+\\b(s\\/o|d\\/o|a\\/l|a\\/p)?\\b[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*$)",
          "maximum": 255,
          "minimum": 1
        },
        "email": {
          "maximum": 100,
          "format": "email"
        },
        "password": {
          "pattern": "(^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+\\b(s\\/o|d\\/o|a\\/l|a\\/p)?\\b[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*$)",
          "maximum": 25,
          "minimum": 8
        }
      }
    },
    "confidential": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["id", "version", "type"],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "maximum": 55,
          "minimum": 4
        },
        "version": {
          "maximum": 100,
          "type": "number"
        },
        "type": {
          "enum": ["Admin", "Customer"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["doc_number", "category"],
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
    },
    "confidential": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/confidential"
    },
    "doc_number": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "category": {
      "enum": ["Private", "Public"]
    }
  }
}
```

> Sample of JSON code is given below

```
{
    "doc_number":12345,
    "category": "Private",
    "user":{
        "name":"Nikola Tesla",
        "email":"tesla@teslaNik.com",
        "password":"Rvpwv84nExp#E@c"
    },
    "confidential":{
        "type":"Customer",
        "version":2.3,
        "id":784562
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added if/then clause in at the top level of my schema, at the same level as the "properties" and "required" keywords.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["name", "email"],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "pattern": "(^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+\\b(s\\/o|d\\/o|a\\/l|a\\/p)?\\b[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*$)",
          "maximum": 255,
          "minimum": 1
        },
        "email": {
          "maximum": 100,
          "format": "email"
        },
        "password": {
          "pattern": "(^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+\\b(s\\/o|d\\/o|a\\/l|a\\/p)?\\b[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*$)",
          "maximum": 25,
          "minimum": 8
        }
      }
    },
    "confidential": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["id", "version", "type"],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "maximum": 55,
          "minimum": 4
        },
        "version": {
          "maximum": 100,
          "type": "number"
        },
        "type": {
          "enum": ["Admin", "Customer"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["doc_number", "category"],
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
    },
    "confidential": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/confidential"
    },
    "doc_number": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "category": {
      "enum": ["Private", "Public"]
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "category": {
        "const": "Private"
      },
      "confidential": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "Customer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "user": {
        "required": ["password"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the top level of your schema, at the same level as the "properties" and "required" keywords, add an if/then clause that spells out all the criteria:

- the category property must exist (`required`), and its value must be a certain value (`const`)
- the confidential property must exist (`required`), and its value must be a certain value (`const`)

Comment: Can you please give me an example?